# Getting "Unregistered interface" for everything I do

Tags: windows-7

I have a Windows 7 x64 PC and I have a weird problem.

Whenever I download a file with Google Chrome, if I click it in the downloads bar, it says "Unregistered interface" instead of opening the file.

Same thing if I go to Desktop, click the right button and select "Screen Resolution" or "Customize".

If I go to the control panel and click "Edit screen resolution", nothing happens.

What is this? How can it be solved?

Answer (score 0):

That's a weird issue. Sounds like something is interferring with Windows system files. Have you installed anything recently that may cause this behaviour?

Also please do the System File Check so to make sure your system is functioning correctly.

Open a new command window (CMD)

Then type `sfc /scannow` and press Enter. This will start scan and it will automatically correct any errors if found.

After the scan please reboot your system and check if the problem persists. If it does, let me know then we'll further investigate your problem.

Finally you might want to scan your system for virusses and other infections using the Free version of [MalwareBytes](http://www.malwarebytes.org/)

Comment: I tried sfc and chkdsk too but they shown no error. I'm thinking that the SSD is going to stop working. Is there a way to know if it is the SSD which is damaged or if it's the motherboard?